# Why does my lua 'class' report an attempt to index global object error?

Tags: lua

The following code is in a file named object.lua:

```
function object:new()
  local instance = {}
  setmetatable(instance, self)
  self.__index = self
  return instance
end
```

In a main file I have:

```
local object = require("object")
local obj = object:new()
```

The error reported is:
lua ./object.lua:1: attempt to index global 'object' (a nil value)

Line #1 is the first line with 'function object:new()'

In main it's the first line (with require).

Code created from:
http://www.lua.org/pil/16.1.html

Edit:

Please see this page:
http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/09/29/tutorial-modular-classes-in-corona/

Then search for 'james' it will be the first comment post and you can see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why can't you just put that in this post? We shouldn't have to look at some other website just to see what you're really asking for.

Comment: Apologies, at the time I didn't think it would be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

main.lua

```
require("object")
local obj = object:new()
```

object.lua

```
object = {}

function object:new()
    local instance = {}
    setmetatable(instance, self)
    self.__index = self
    return instance
end
```

You are declaring a global "object" in object.lua, not returning it, so you just need to do `require("object")`

Comment: You also have to return `object`. And you shouldn't make it global in the module.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much.  Lua is kind of a headache coming from an OOP background.

Comment: @NicolBolas Can you provide a code example? Doesn't this seem to go against the point of the class?  I know how to instantiate a class in a different way, but this way was recommended to avoid having to create global declarations.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that when the code in object.lua is run and you attempt to create the object:new function there is no object table to create it in.

Dogbert's solution works fine in that object.lua creates the object table before using it. However, it does so by explicitly creating a global and then expecting callers to have found that which is not the best solution. The amended solution provided by Nicol Bolas... that of creating a local object in object.lua and returning it is the more generally agreed upon pattern for this sort of task.